# Retrieve the input text from HTML after parsing

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I am new to PHP and DOMDocument, I have couple of doubts

1)

```
..
<input type ="text" name ='name'>
..
<input type = "text" name='password'>
```

Later, At the server I would like to parse this php document before it is interpreted. I would like to know what the user has inserted, edit it in the format I want and then send it to PHP interpreter.
I want to get all text inserted in all the input tags in a particular document. Is this possible?

edit: After clicking the send button say he typed name as "XYZ", and password as "ABC". I want my program to grab these 2 texts and edit it. Like i want my program to add this text "123" to end of all the strings that come from input tag so my name = "XYZ123" and password is "ABC123". Now this text should be sent to server for further processing.

2) If I want to do this process each time this page is sent to server and extend it for all pages, how should  I go about it? 
Where should I place this program that scans edit and later sends it for interpretation?

Comment: Can you explain " I would like to know what the user has inserted, edit it in the format I want and then send it to php interpreter." better?

Comment: i have edited the Q and tried to explain my Q with an example.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has submitted the form, then the data will be in $_GET or $_POST (depending on the method used to submit the form, $_REQUEST will contain both, along with user data from other sources).

If they haven't submitted the form, then you won't normally be sent the data. You could use JavaScript to send the data to the server as the user enters it (think Google instant).

Comment: I want something like... say for eg: Google takes search query as text and say a spell mistake is observed by google program at the server. The program will edit the text appropriately and then send it to server for further processing automatically. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @prap19 If what you say above is correct, then the only way to do this is with JavaScript since PHP only operates on the server. It can't capture anything before it is sent to the server because it only exists on the server.

Comment: so its not possible to extract the text before it is sent to server? or is it possible to edit the text before it is sent to database from web server?